# Conditional Formatting, using an formula to format based on different cell value range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use a conditional format formula but I cannot figure out how to write it correctly.  Attached is an image of the data set that I'm working with.  [Dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7KGQ.jpg)

Ideally, temperature values in column B will highlight red if they are out of their + or - 0.5 degree range based on which tank they are in. Previously I selected the individual cells that are associated with a specific tank to format based on the range (i.e. cell value not between =$F$4-0.5 and $F$4+0.5 then format red) but it is a pain to individually select each cell when the instrument changes tanks weekly.

Is there any way to tell it to format B6 based on D6 such that it uses the conditional format of "cell value not between =$F$4-0.5 and $F$4+0.5 then format red"?

Comment: So you want to use either F4 or E4 depending on the value in column E?

Comment: I'd like to use either F4 or E4 based on the value in column D (the tank).

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula for the format rule:

```
=ABS(B6-IF(E6=$E$3,$E$4,$F$4))>0.5
```

It will fill down.

**EDIT.** Explanation: The `IF` statement will return the temperature in `E4:F4` corresponding to the Tank DO in column E. We then check if the absolute value of the difference of that and the DO from column C is within the 0.5° range that you specified. So for B6, the formula will calculate like this:

```
=ABS(B6-IF(E6=$E$3,$E$4,$F$4))>0.5
=ABS(B6-IF(8.44=8.48,$E$4,$F$4))>0.5
=ABS(B6-IF(FALSE,$E$4,$F$4))>0.5
=ABS(B6-$F$4)>0.5
=ABS(23.81-23.30)>0.5
=ABS(0.51)>0.5
=0.51>0.5
=TRUE --> the conditional formatting will be applied
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Corrected wrong cell reference.

<sup>*Thanks to superstar [@PNUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516488/conditional-formatting-using-an-formula-to-format-based-on-different-cell-value/50516737?noredirect=1#comment88049961_50516737) for pointing out my error.*</sup>

---

You could use:

```
=ABS(B6-$F$4)<=0.5
```

Whichever one you use (they'll give the same result), make that the conditional formatting for cell `B6` and then copy & paste formatting to the rest of the cells in the column.

Note that the placement of the `$` (absolute cell reference indicators).

The **[`ABS` function](https://support.office.com/article/abs-function-3420200f-5628-4e8c-99da-c99d7c87713c)** returns the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a number (*"the distance from zero"*, or more simply, *"makes a negative number positive"*) so there is no need for "between", but if you did need to use multiple criteria (as if to mimic "between") you could use the **[AND function](https://support.office.com/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9)**, something like:

```
=AND(B6-$F$4>=-0.5,B6-$F$4<=0.5)
```

A good way to test "more complex" conditional formatting criteria is to enter them in a cell.  Any formula that returns only `TRUE` or `FALSE` will work in conditional formatting.  (`TRUE` = apply formatting)

A simpler demonstration of how formulas with multiple `=` ([equality signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign)) work is enter these formulas into cells:

```
=1=1   (this will return TRUE)
=1=2   (this will return FALSE)
```

...and thus are the equivalent of:

```
=IF(1=1,TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(1=2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Use formulas with conditional formatting**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)
- Office.com : [**`AND` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9)
- Office.com : [**`ABS` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/abs-function-3420200f-5628-4e8c-99da-c99d7c87713c)
- TechRepublic : [**10 cool ways to use Excel's conditional formatting feature**](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-cool-ways-to-use-excels-conditional-formatting-feature/)
- Office.com : [**Quick start: Apply conditional formatting** (Tutorial)](https://support.office.com/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67)

Comment: @pnuts corrected cell reference.  re: `TRUE`/`FALSE` what is an example of a formula that would not work?